# How to redirect my previous page after SSO Login in spring security?

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-security, single-sign-on

How to redirect my previous page after SSO Login in spring security

I used set userReferer as true ,

But not able achieve it.  please suggest some sample code or site.

Spring security with IDP we are using

```
public class LoginSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler
        implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    private RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();

    public LoginSuccessHandler() {
        super();
        setUseReferer(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {

        /// some code 

        //set our response to OK status
        httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);

        String targetUrl = determineTargetUrl(authentication);

        httpServletResponse.sendRedirect(targetUrl);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Once the user gets authenticated on IDP (Identity provider) side then SP (Service provider) receives assertions or response from IDP. That response would be validated on SP side. Upon response validation, this class `OAuthUserLoginSuccessHandler` would be called, where you can extract the information from the response provided by IDP and proceed with redirection as per the following code.

```
  import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
  import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
  import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler;

  public class OAuthUserLoginSuccessHandler extends 
      SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler {
   public OAuthUserLoginSuccessHandler() {}

   @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(final HttpServletRequest request,
     final HttpServletResponse response, final Authentication authentication)
     throws IOException, ServletException {

    if (authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof UserDetails
         || authentication.getDetails() instanceof UserDetails) {
    UserDetails details;

    if (authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof UserDetails) {
      details = (UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
    } else {
      details = (UserDetails) authentication.getDetails();
    }

    String username = details.getUsername();
    // get user info from datastore using username 
    // some code 
 
    String redirectUri;  // get target uri either from relay state or from datastore
    if (null != redirectUri) {
       response.sendRedirect(redirectUri);
       return;
     }
   }
   super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.